# Scrapy Scraper not scraping further than first page

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to create a spider that starts on a wikipedia page called https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Korea_and_weapons_of_mass_destruction and then scrapes the text and image files I feed it to. It appears to be kind of working except I only get the first response (doesn't go to the following pages. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import Request
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor 
import re

BASE_URL = 'http://en.wikipedia.org'
PROTOCOL = 'https:'


class MissleSpiderBio(scrapy.Spider): 

    name = 'weapons_bio'
    allowed_domains = ['https://en.wikipedia.org']
    start_urls = ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/...'] //url above


    def parse(self, response):
        filename = response.url.split('/')[-1]
        h4s = response.xpath('//h4')

        text = response.css("#mw-content-text > div > p:nth- \
        child(2)::text").extract()
        if text:
            images = response.css("#mw-content-text > div > table> 
            tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td > a > 
            img::attr(src)").extract()
            yield {'body': text, 'image_urls':[PROTOCOL+ 
            images[0]]}

        else:
            yield {'empty': "not found"}

        for next_page in response.css('#mw-content-text > div > ul 
        > li  > b > a::attr(href)').extract():
            print(BASE_URL + next_page)
            yield response.follow(BASE_URL + next_page, \ 
            callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: Instead of `yield response.follow` please try `yield Request` ... and also tell me do you see output of `print(BASE_URL + next_page)`?

Comment: @Umair tried it with Request and I get the same results. also, yes, i see the output of the print with the full urls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things you can try

instead of `http` in

```
BASE_URL = 'http://en.wikipedia.org'
```

set it to

```
BASE_URL = 'https://en.wikipedia.org'
```

2nd thing, comment out this line

```
allowed_domains = ['https://en.wikipedia.org']
```

I think that is why it is not following the link